# appendComponentToBody is not working in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

appendComponentToBody is not working in my code..I can not findout where I did mistake.Please help me how to resolve this issue.

See my code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axhgid?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.ts

dialog.component.ts

```
 constructor(private domService: ModalService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
 this.domService.appendComponentToBody(DialogComponent);
 }
```

Comment: Please refer: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

I think you haven't specified entryComponents: [DialogComponent] is NgModule. You might be missing on something else as well, please do have a check

Comment: Mithil Mohan:I am new in angular2 So can you edit my stackblitz code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a created a Simple Example adding a component dynamically and removing it using two buttons.

Please have a look, it doesn't have complications.

**Refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvnue8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal.service.ts**

Now edit it to suit your needs

It was difficult to comprehend your code and hence I made this snippet for you

Comment: Refer : https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef for method definitions